# How to detect whose face this is in OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, detection

I have a set of face portrait images (2k) with names. I have an HD video stream on which I detected faces and tracked them. For each person on each frame I have say 5-10 similar yet different photo frame chunks with 20x20 to 100x100 sizes. I wonder what would be the way to correlate my detected faces with given portraint in OpenCV in Python or C++?

Comment: Face recognition isn't easy. Definitely beyond a SO answer. With 20x20 the error will be quite large and if the angle of the head is any different from database photo, it's straight up useless. Do provide some more specifics before I can tell if I can help. Does database have only 1 photo per person? Realtime recognition with several people at the same time too is unlikely. Can you make a manually recognized database of captured face rectangles?

Comment: @IcedLance: 1 photo per person, say HD video of a town hall meeting - camera is static above stage. Offline recognition. I thought of only eigenfaces so far yet I wonder what can help\change from having sequences of same person face images (having them at such low resolution)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While writing all that below I remembered [this thing](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition), that is the first google result for "face recognition", but I never really tried it, so can't comment.

With the setting you described Eigenfaces would work to an extent. It would be ideal, if stage was raised somewhat and camera installed in the podium, so that most of the time everyone looked straight at it, but alas.

I'll just try to list things you can do/try to improve the result in no particular order.

- I personally mostly deal with Neural Networks, so my first guess was to try OpenFace, but it's a rather expensive method to both train and run (needs a bigger database with multiple pictures per person etc; recognition time up to a second per face), and it's maybe an overkill for the task. Still maybe you'll find something interesting for you [here](https://blog.algorithmia.com/understanding-facial-recognition-openface/).
- The first problem you have is pictures in database are probably portrait shots, but camera will pick them up facing down relative to it.You'll need some preprocessing before recognition to adjust for that depending on the angle. Good thing is further people are sitting the less distorted the face is, even though quality is worse. There're 2 ways to do it.

  1. One is to pick up distinct features (eyes + nose tip) and affine transform until they match the standard that is rather simple, but you lose some information, like nose length etc. And you'll have to do the same for database pictures before you train.
  2. The other is to do it yourself by using face ROI coordinates in picture and transform based on that. It's easier and now that I think about it may even be more reliable. However it doesn't correct face tilt and maybe some other things.

That all might fall apart if angles are too big, but idk.

- Second thing is heuristics based on the fact, that it's a video rather than a still shot. We used it for number plate recognition, but it's rather straightforward. The idea is you have an array of objects, that are recognized faces. Every frame you check if detected face corresponds to one of the pre-existing objects. The factors are both distance and similarity to past classifier responses. You record the classifier responses and the guesses it makes, based on those you accumulate confidence in particular guesses (a lot of heuristics here, like accumulating more if there're no close alternative guesses, taking detector response into account etc). Once you don't detect that face in some frame you keep object alive for some arbitrary time, maybe even run detector on a particular region again with relaxed parameters. You get the idea I hope. That's just a buttload of heuristics.
- Then after you do run recognition on some video you can take some frames of faces recognized with high confidence (or filter them by hand) and run more training on them to reinforce the model.
- Might also add a small step of changing if person has sunglasses/baseball cap on and adjust accordingly. (I'd say too much interference and you should give up, but you can add corresponding cases to training or deal with it in some other way) It shouldn't add too much to processing time, as detecting sunglasses with good enough confidence shouldn't be too hard. When dealing with number plates we had a whole cascade of tiny NNs checking for all kinds of things before the big ones even start acting.
- I noticed most face detectors return ROI too small (like cutting out hair etc), might want to expand it a little, but it might be not necessary.